# Свойства Explorer.exe в системе Windows

Tags: windows, explorer

Хотелось бы узнать некоторые свойства эксплорера windows.

1. Если вместо "Explorer.exe" подставить другую программу, то после перезагрузки
   она будет считаться главным окном системы, т.е рабочим столом ?
2. Запустится ли с цифровых носителей Autorun.inf, если, опять же "Explorer.exe" заменить на другую программу?

Comment: проверьте же опытным путем )

Comment: Страшновато...

Answer (score 1):

1. Вероятно, да.
   Но оболочку Windows можно поменять через параметр реестра на любую программу.
   Например, `progman`.
2. Нет. Автозапуск реализуется именно проводником.
3. Системный автозапуск тоже реализуется проводником и не сработает.
   Естественно, на службы это не распространяется.
4. В Win7 поведение Alt+Tab c предпросмотром окон тоже связано с проводником.
   Вероятно, внешний вид сведётся к значкам, как в XP.

Answer (score 0):

Знаю точно, что при удаление explorer.exe можно запускать любые приложения через диспетчер задач. Видел даже у разработчиков ПО фишку,они специально убирали explorer.exe и оставляли по центру на рабочем столе утилиты с запуском приложений,которые разработаны специально для   внешнего устройства управления аппаратурой. Делается это всё для защиты винды от неопытных Юзеров. Вот так вот.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно же, но зачем мне это? Это не ответ на МОЙ вопрос, а просто пояснение чего-то.